# To convert any type of javascript datetime variable to moment JS object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, momentjs, angular-moment

Is there a way where we can detect/convert an incoming variable of type/format of UTC or Moment JS Object or `Date()` object or a plain string containing `datetime`, to a common format of Moment JS object?

Example:

```
"1509760983",
Date 2017-10-10T02:20:10.570Z,
Object { _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _locale: Object, _d: Date 2017-11-04T02:17:33.747Z, _z: null },
"Sat, 04 Nov 2017 02:03:03 GMT",
"2017-11-04T02:20:14.896Z"
```

**My hack:**

```
var offset = moment().utcOffset();
momentObj = moment(variable).utcOffset(offset);
```

I was able to convert all other formats to Moment JS without any "deviation" in the data, except if the variable is already a `Date()` object.

```
var offset = moment().utcOffset();
momentObj = (variable instanceof Date) ? moment(variable) : moment(variable).utcOffset(offset);
```

**Note:** Since a `Date()` object can only be generated in the browser, so there is no need to add offset to convert the time to local timezone.

Is there a better (fail-safe) approach to this solution?

Comment: Have a look at [`moment.utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/): _By default, moment parses and displays in local time. If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use `moment.utc()` instead of `moment()`_

Comment: @VincenzoC The req. is to display all the input `datetime` in local time, no matter what time format they are in. That's the reason to have added the offset.

Comment: I do not fully get what you are trying to do, can you provide a snippet or a fiddle and an example of your expected result? Anyway have a look at [`local()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/) function to convert moment object to local mode (default). See [Local vs UTC vs Offset](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/) guide too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last char of the javascript date "Z" shows that the object's timezone is set to UTC (Z time, zulu time). You are getting thè correct timezone. If you want to convert the timezone to the local one, you should use [moment timezone plugin](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) with moment.js.

Then you would do:

```
momentObj = moment(variable).tz(moment.tz.guess());
```

to convert/set all moment objects to the user's timezone.